# Remove select value of query2 that query1 have

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Table PM:
user1 | user2 | message | timestamp | read1

Query1:

```
SELECT count(message) as noOfReplies,user1 
FROM `pm` 
WHERE user2='Henry' and read1='' 
GROUP BY user1
```

Output:

[image: output1]

Query2:

```
SELECT count(message) as replies, 
if (user1='henry',user2,user1) as user,timestamp 
FROM `pm` 
WHERE read1='yes' and if(user1='henry',user1,user2) = 'henry' 
GROUP BY if(user1='henry',user2,user1)
```

Output:

[image: output 2]

What I'm trying to do is remove coleen from the output of query2 because that row already displays from query1

What I've tried is like this:

```
SELECT count(message) as replies, if (user1='henry',user2,user1) as user
FROM `pm` 
WHERE read1='yes'and if(user1='henry',user1,user2) not in 
( 
    SELECT count(message) as noOfReplies,user1 
    FROM `pm` WHERE user2='Henry' and read1='' 
    GROUP BY  user1
)
and if(user1='henry',user1,user2) = 'henry'
GROUP BY  if(user1='henry',user2,user1)
```

But I'm getting an error #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Just so you know, your two images reference the same hyperlink in your markdown, you probably want to edit one of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from the fact that the select in `NOT IN` must return only one column. To avoid the error, try something like :

```
SELECT count(message) as replies, if (user1='henry',user2,user1) as user
FROM `pm` 
WHERE read1='yes'and if(user1='henry',user1,user2) not in 
( 
    SELECT user1 -- here, ONE column
    FROM `pm` WHERE user2='Henry' and read1='' 
)
and if(user1='henry',user1,user2) = 'henry'
GROUP BY  if(user1='henry',user2,user1)
```

But there are some things I don't understand in your logic. For example, if your `if` is false, you will check if `user2` is in a list `user1`... Is this what you want ?

Comment: first if is if user1 = henry i will get the value of user2
second one is if user1 = henry  then user = henry if not user2 = henry

anyway really thanks for the answer it help me a lot to get what i want